# What time does Googlebot crawl sites

Tags: googlebot

Daily evening I sync the localhost copy of website to the production one. Yesterday I could not do it and I did so today at 10:00 am.

Common sense says that Googlebot should be crawling the site when it is most idle which is during night in that country.

**So I want to know what is the actual time it does so.** Moreover I don't think Google has disclosed this. I've googled for this .. but found nothing.

Comment: Around the clock. With the whole world and many timezones, common sense says that it's a continuous operation open to any server resource Google has available. If you want to control when on your server, sign up for Google Webmaster tools.

Comment: you can only slow down crawl rate but not choose time for it. I once saw my site choking at night by heavy crawl requests from Google & Bing

Answer (score 1):

Any time it wants. Could be anytime of the day or night depending on the particular bot crawler and the method/approach it takes to visit your site.